PrimeVue Datatable paginator with Laravel SSR paginate
Is it possibile to control the next and prev buttons of primevues Datatable with pagination enabled  combined with laravel ssr paginate method of the models?
This is my DataTable
<DataTable
    v-if="!isCreating"
    paginator
    :rows="10"
    v-model:editingRows="editingRows"
    v-model:selection="selectedProducts"
    :value="props.tax_payer_categories.data"
    :total-records="props.tax_payer_categories.total"
    editMode="row"
    paginatorTemplate="RowsPerPageDropdown FirstPageLink PrevPageLink CurrentPageReport NextPageLink LastPageLink"
    @row-edit-save="onRowEditSave"
    dataKey="id"
    striped-rows
    table-class="p-10"
    :pt="{
        table: { style: 'min-width: 50rem' },
        column: {
            bodycell: () => ({
                style: 'padding-top: 1rem; padding-bottom: 0.6rem; place-content: flex-start;',
            }),
        },
    }"
>

My laravel controller :
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('TaxPayerCategory/Index', [
                'tax_payer_categories' => TaxPayerCategory::paginate(10)
    ]);
}


What's the question? Do you have pagination on the backend?

Yes i do have pagination from the backend, my question is how to handle pagination change from the dataTable component from PrimeVue
